# How can I search for answers which are longer than a given length?

Tags: support, search

If I just want extensive answers, how could I search for questions which have accepted answers with a length of at least 500 characters?

Comment: Use data explorer. Search doesn't support this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Data Explorer][1], which is updated weekly (it doesn't appear as though timeliness is of importance to you).

This query would get you what you want, and you can add whatever other filters/joins etc. you want:

500

I've created [a more generic version][2] where you can input whatever length you want. It's limited to the top 100 records 'cause timeouts :-(.

[1]: https://data.stackexchange.com/
[2]: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/411818/answers-by-length?postlength=500

Comment: Not that I think there's anything better, but I can just hear a DBA somewhere screaming about that query.  Column function in where clause.

Comment: You're thinking about OLTP systems @ryanyuyu; this wouldn't be that non-standard in an OLAP DB. Given the frequency of this query running vs the necessary maintenance of a PostLength column I'd normally judge using a function as acceptable.